# How to display two controllers in one window and talk to each other

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to iOS app (iPad) development ,  need to create an app for restaurant, i need to display the categories and subcategories in right side of the iPad (display like collection view)and while clicking the subcategories bill details should be display in left side of the same window in iPad.when clicking the items in subcategory those item should be placed in the billing area and display the related billing information.

Please anyone suggest me to how to do that, and any example like that?

Answer (score 0):

By using `UISplitViewController` you will get what you want. If you're using storyboard you can choose it from `object library` ant it will automatically create a visual representation of VCs on storyboard.

This is the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) for it.

If you want more complex operation and more personalized stuff you can use 'UIContainerView`, when you put it in your Main View Controller you will get the next view controller connected with`segue`. And then from your mainVC you can access childVCs by`self.childViewControllers` Here is how it looks like:

[image]

But `UISplitViewController` should be enough for you.

Comment: thanks for your reply, is it possible to elaborate little bit more about the custom view container ?do you have any example on that?, but splitview controller is working as master-detail which are placed on left,right side respectively.is it possible to change it to display the master detail in right side and detail view in leftside?

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need two `view Controllers` for this, You can do it using `single view controller`.

Divide the screen in two sections put two views,

**1st View :** First view Will be on the left Side which will contain the categories and subcategories

**2nd View** : Second view will be on the right side which will show bill details.

You can have **separate classes** for these views if you want to do more detailing in it.

This is the simple technique, you can also go for the `UISplitViewController`

**Hope this will help you.**